# Kubernetes PV refuses to bind after delete/re-create

Tags: kubernetes

Given the following PVC and PV:

- PVC:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: packages-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
  volumeName: packages-volume
```

- PV:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: packages-volume
  namespace: test
spec:
  claimRef:
    name: packages-pvc
    namespace: test
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  nfs:
    path: {{NFS_PATH}}
    server: {{NFS_SERVER}}
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
```

if I create the PV, then the PVC, they bind together. However if I delete the PVC then re-create it, they do not bind (pvc pending). Why?

Comment: Can you please share steps to create a new PVC and add the released PVC to it ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Note that after deleting `PVC`, `PV` remains in `Released` status:

```
$ kubectl get pv packages-volume
NAME              CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS     CLAIM                  STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE
packages-volume   1007Gi     RWX            Retain           Released   default/packages-pvc                           10m
```

It should have status `Available` so it can be reused by another `PersistentVolumeClaim` instance.

**Why it isn't `Available` ?**

If you display current `yaml` definition of the `PV`, which you can easily do by executing:

```
kubectl get pv packages-volume -o yaml
```

you may notice that in `claimRef` section it contains the `uid` of the recently deleted `PersistentVolumeClaim`:

```
  claimRef:
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
    name: packages-pvc
    namespace: default
    resourceVersion: "10218121"
    uid: 1aede3e6-eaa1-11e9-a594-42010a9c0005
```

You can easily verify it by issuing:

```
kubectl get pvc packages-pvc -o yaml | grep uid
```

just before you delete your `PVC` and compare it with what `PV` definition contains. You'll see that this is exactly the same `uid` that is still referred by your `PV` after `PVC` is deleted. This remaining reference is the actual reason that `PV` remains in `Released` status.

**Why newly created `PVC` remains in a `Pending` state ?**

Although your newly created `PVC` may seem to you exactly the same `PVC` that you've just deleted as you're creating it using the very same `yaml` file, from the perspective of `Kubernetes` it's a completely new instance of `PersistentVolumeClaim` object which has completely different `uid`. This is the reason why it remains in `Pending` status and is unable to bind to the `PV`.

**Solution:**

To make the `PV` `Available` again you just need to remove the mentioned `uid` reference e.g. by issuing:

```
kubectl patch pv packages-volume --type json -p '[{"op": "remove", "path": "/spec/claimRef/uid"}]'
```

or alternatively by removing the whole `claimRef` section which can be done as follows:

```
kubectl patch pv packages-volume --type json -p '[{"op": "remove", "path": "/spec/claimRef"}]'
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Why is Kubernetes creating that `uid` anyway and are there ways to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

the above answer solves the problem. however there is a reason that PV is kept into released stated.  k8s controller can easily remove the PVC ref after the user deletes the PVC claim and brings the PV to be in available state.

But there is a problem, once a PV goes into bound state, it's must have some data. if you forcefully bind it, you will loose or corrupt your data.

so you must backup/clean the PV, before you try to make it available.

thanks